# All Attributes from a tags

Tags: php, dom

How can I get all attributes from a tags?

```
<a href="URL1">TEXT 1</a>
<a href="URL2" rel="rel2">TEXT 2</a>
<a href="URL3" rel="me" target="_blank">TEXT 3</a>
```

How can I get this result with PHP? Is there any way to do this with PHP DOMDocument?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [href] => URL1
            [text] => TEXT 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [href] => URL2
            [text] => TEXT 2
            [rel] => rel2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [href] => URL3
            [text] => TEXT 3
            [rel] => me
            [target] => _blank
        )

)
```

Comment: The html is on browser (in client side) or on your server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes for a node can be retrieved using [`DOMNode::attributes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes) which is a [`DOMNamedNodeMap`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnamednodemap.php) but can be used like an array:

```
$html = '<a href="URL1">TEXT 1</a><a href="URL2" rel="rel2">TEXT 2</a><a href="URL3" rel="me" target="_blank">TEXT 3</a>';

$output = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $a)
{
    $attrList = array();
    if($a->hasAttributes())
    {
        foreach ($a->attributes as $attribute)
        {
            $attrList[$attribute->nodeName] = $attribute->nodeValue
            $attrList['text'] = $a->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    $output[] = $attrList;
}

print_r($output);
```

**Outputs**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [href] => URL1
            [text] => TEXT 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [href] => URL2
            [text] => TEXT 2
            [rel] => rel2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [href] => URL3
            [text] => TEXT 3
            [rel] => me
            [target] => _blank
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($the_html);
```

Then parse using DomDocument methods (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Something like this should work

```
$a = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
if ($a->hasAttributes()) {
  foreach ($a->attributes as $attribute) {
    $name = $attribute->nodeName;
    $value = $attribute->nodeValue;
    echo "Attribute '$name' => '$value'<br />";
  }
}
```